# Jasmine toThrow() syntax

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have an activity I am doing for an apprenticeship opportunity and the main engineer that I could discuss this with is not responding so I figure I ask on here.
Basically this is a 'triangle' exercise with the main purpose of writing in TDD with jasmine.

Now, I have written the simple ones and when I moved to writing the edge cases, I am having trouble with throwing invalid input. Looking at the Docs it seems simple but my test fails with `invalid thrown` as error

```
describe('Triangle', function(){
var Triangle = function(x, y, z){
  if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0) {
    throw 'invalid';}
  if(x === y && y === z){
    return 'equilateral';}
  if(x === y || x === z || y === z){
  return 'isosceles';}
  else{return 'scalene';}    
};

  it('test triangles with no size are illegal', function() {
    var triangle = Triangle(0,0,0);
    expect(triangle).toThrow();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are actually calling the function here:

```
var triangle = Triangle(0,0,0);
```

Instead, you should let `expect()` call it by providing a *callable*:

```
expect(function() { Triangle(0, 0, 0); }).toThrow();
```

Comment: i saw that mention somewhere before but it still fails

Comment: @BennySaxeman have you removed the `var triangle = Triangle(0,0,0);` line?

Comment: Yes I did, it is still failing

Comment: @BennySaxeman there is something you are doing incorrectly. Please see this jsfiddle - see the test passes: https://jsfiddle.net/aza03o54/. Thanks.

Comment: not sure why, but copy of the code from jsfiddle works but not from here. Thanks @alecxe